# Set value in a new column, based on an end of a string in another column, for every type of different endings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in Pandas, which contains certain string endings of the first column, but, by using np.where/df.where i can set only two values, one if it meets the criteria, and another if not.

I've tried to filter different df from the original one (based on the value in the first column) and adding the new column there, then creating a new df with pd.concat, and its working.

```
reference_list = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", ...]

df["newcolumn"] = np.where(df["column1"].str.endswith(reference_list), "value", "other")
```

btw if i do like above everytime it finds a value that is in the reference list it adds "value" to the new column, but i want that value to be the same it finds in the reference list
i'd like to have something like this

```
df["newcolumn"] = np.where(df["column1"].str.endswith(reference_list), reference_list_value, "other")
```

this is the df i get

```
column1   new_column
AAABBB    value
AAACCC    value
BBBCCC    value
BBBAAA    value
```

this is the df i want

```
column1   new_column
AAABBB    BBB
AAACCC    CCC
BBBCCC    CCC
BBBAAA    AAA
```

Thaks for helping

Comment: Thanks, but i forgot to mention, the endings in the list can be 3 to 5 characters long

Comment: x = "("+ "|".join(reference_list) + ")" +"$" and                                                               df["new_column"] = df["column1"].str.extract(x).fillna("other") has worked, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.extract` and capture group:

```
df:
  column1
0  AAABBB
1  AAACCC
2  BBBCCC
3  BBBAAA
4  FFFFFF
```

Try the following:

```
s = '|'.join(['('+item+'$)' for item in reference_list])
df['new_column'] = df.column1.str.extract(s, expand=True).bfill(axis=1)[0].fillna('other')

df:
  column1 new_column
0  AAABBB        BBB
1  AAACCC        CCC
2  BBBCCC        CCC
3  BBBAAA        AAA
4  FFFFFF      other
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following list comprehension:

```
df["newcolumn"] = [s for i in df.column1 for s in reference_list if i.endswith(s)]
```

---

```
print(df)

   column1 newcolumn
0  AAABBB       BBB
1  AAACCC       CCC
2  BBBCCC       CCC
3  BBBAAA       AAA
```

Comment: I'm using an example dataframe @hacker315

Comment: The df he wants should contain the` endings` and not '`value'`

Comment: Ohhh right. Let me change the solution then thanks @hacker315

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
l = lambda x: re.search( "|".join(reference_list) + "$", x ).group(0)
df['column1'].apply(l ,1)
```